# Curl with multiline of JSON

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, curl

Consider the curl command below, is it possible to allow newline in JSON (without the minify) and execute directly in bash (Mac/Ubuntu)

```
curl -0 -v -X POST http://www.example.com/api/users \
-H "Expect:" \
-H 'Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8' \
-d \
'
{
    "field1": "test",
    "field2": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}'
```

When I run the command above, seems error occurred at the `second {`
How to fix the above command?

**Updated**: actually I was able to run the command without issue previously, not sure why problem happen recently.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the error?  Your example works "as is" on my system.

    `mymac > bash --version
    GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
    Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Yup, works for me as well: `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release`

Comment: Also check out [ANSI C-like string syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting): `echo $'here is a newline:\nand here is a tab:\t'`

Comment: `application/json` is the correct media type for JSON data -- see [RFC4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Answer (score 219):

I remembered another way to do this with a "Here Document" as described in the Bash man page and [detailed here](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/here-docs.html).  The `@-` means to read the body from STDIN, while `<< EOF` means to pipe the script content until "EOF" as STDIN to curl.  This layout may be easier to read than using separate files or the "echo a variable" approach.

```
curl -0 -v -X POST http://www.example.com/api/users \
-H "Expect:" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
--data-binary @- << EOF
{
    "field1": "test",
    "field2": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
EOF
```

NOTE: Use the `--trace <outfile>` curl option to record *exactly* what goes over the wire.  For some reason, this Here Document approach strips newlines.  (Update: Newlines were stripped by curl -d option.  Corrected!)

Comment: This is clean, no extra quoting, no escaping and it works very well. Thanks.

Comment: Can we use pipes with such a syntax?

Comment: Yes you can pipe the output to another command, although the placement is right in the middle.  Add the stdout redirect after the stdin redirect.  Example using word count:
`-d @- << EOF | wc`

Comment: It's not Here Document that strips new lines, but `curl -d` option: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d. Use `--data-binary` to keep newline and carriage return characters.

Comment: Can you insert variables into the JSON? I don't think so.

Comment: You most certainly can insert variables!  See what happens when you replace "foo": "bar" with "$SHELL": "$(date)".

Comment: This works like a charm. And it also supports passing values to the JSON with ${VAR} 

Comment: Finally, I found a great solution for this! Thank you. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 58):

Along the lines of Martin's suggestion of putting the JSON in a variable, you could also put the JSON in a separate file, and then supply the filename to `-d` using curl's @ syntax:

```
curl -0 -v -X POST http://www.example.com/api/users \
  -H "Expect:" \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -d @myfile.json
```

The disadvantage is obvious (2 or more files where you used to have one.) But on the plus side, your script could accept a filename or directory argument and you'd never need to edit it, just run it on different JSON files. Whether that's useful depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Note: make sure you've valid json content through https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: This approach is clean and easy to debug compared to others.

Comment: Great solution. Be careful of PATH tho !

Answer (score 36):

> For some reason, this Here Document approach strips newlines

@eric-bolinger the reason the Heredoc strips newlines is because you need to tell your Heredoc to preserve newlines by quoting the EOF:

```
curl -0 -v -X POST http://www.example.com/api/users \
-H "Expect:" \
-H 'Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8' \
-d @- <<'EOF'

{
    "field1": "test",
    "field2": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
EOF
```

Notice the single-ticks surrounding EOF the first time it's defined, but not the second.

Answer (score 31):

You should use outer double quotes, and the escape all inner quotes like this:

```
curl -0 -v -X POST http://www.example.com/api/users \
-H "Expect:" \
-H 'Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8' \
-d \
"
{
    \"field1\": \"test\",
    \"field2\": {
        \"foo\": \"bar\"
    }
}"
```

Answer (score 28):

You could assign your json to a var:

```
json='
{
    "field1": "test",
    "field2": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}'
```

Now you can forward this to curl using `stdin`:

```
echo $json | curl -0 -v -X POST http://www.example.com/api/users \
-H "Expect:" \
-H 'Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8' \
-d @-
```

Comment: Using single quotes to surround the block means that you *cannot* use variables (e.g. `${username}`) in the JSON.

Comment: Yup, but using double quotes means you can't use $ signs in your data. Pick which one is right for you.

Answer (score 10):

I think this can be an answer

```sh
curl -0 -v -X POST http://www.example.com/api/users \
-H "Expect:" \
-H 'Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8' \
--data-raw '
{
    "field1": "test",
    "field2": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}'
```

Comment: I like this because it works well even with indentation and if one uses "" quotes, even variables can be used.