# Using Curl to put data into ES and got Unexpected character ('n' (code 110))

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I'm using Curl to put data into ES. I have already created a `customer` index. 
The following command is from [ES document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-query-document.html).

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
'
```

When I do this, I get an error.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "json_parse_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@1ec5236e; line: 3, column: 4]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I think, the below is the main reason of my error.

> reason" : "Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

I have a feeling that I need to use (backslash) to escape. However, my attempt `\'` is not working great. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work like the below.

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
    \"name\": \"John Doe\"             <====  I used "backslash"  in front of all the " 
}
'
```

Answer without my comment:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
    \"name\": \"John Doe\"              
}
'
```

Comment: You can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847981/curl-with-multiline-of-json) for different ways to pass json as curl body parameter