# AWS CLI DynamoDB adding non-key attributes to existing table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am working on a Cloud Computing class project using AWS Command Line Interface to insert a table in DynamoDB. The step I'm stuck on is adding the other non-key attributes to the table. I read through the Help section about adding the attributes and came up with the following:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
--table-name Sensors \
--item '{"SensorDescription": {"S": "A"}, \
"ImageFile": {"S": "file1"}, \
"SampleRate": {"N": "100"}, \
"Locations": {"L": "Aberdeen MD, Warren MI, Orlando FL"} \
--return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

I've tried batch-write-item and re-formatting examples I found through AWS Help but I am still having issues. I've been using Cloud9 for a while but DynamoDB is very new to me. Any help is greatly appreciated. The table Sensors is already created and has the following info:

```
vocstartsoft:~/environment $ aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name Sensors
{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "Sensor",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "Sensors",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "Sensor",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "CreationDateTime": 1607909069.531,
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 0,
        "ItemCount": 0,
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:466773264882:table/Sensors",
        "TableId": "5ddc11bc-8167-4bfa-bbcc-96199954ba39"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have an error to post as well, that could be helpful. However I think you are just missing an ending bracket and single quote on your ```--item``` parameter. I think the error will likely be some kind of unexpected end of json.

Comment: I fixed the missing bracket and single quote but I'm getting this error: Error parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 31 (char 30). I initially thought it was saying each attribute needs more parentheses but it did not work when I added them.

Answer (score 1):

Please, first, be aware that you always need to include the primary key attributes in the [put item operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html).

On the other hand, the list `Locations` is not correctly defined.

Also, be aware that you missed `}'` at the end of the item values.

Please, try something like the following:

```
    aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name Sensors \
    --item '{"Sensor": {"S", "Sensor 1"},
    "SensorDescription": {"S": "A"},
    "ImageFile": {"S": "file1"},
    "SampleRate": {"N": "100"},
    "Locations": {"L": [{"S": "Aberdeen MD"}, {"S": "Warren MI"}, {"S": "Orlando FL"}]}}' \
    --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

For simplicity, and in order to avoid problems with shell continuation characters, you can include the item information in a file, let's name it `item.json`:

```
{
  "Sensor": {"S", "Sensor 1"},
  "SensorDescription": {"S": "A"},
  "ImageFile": {"S": "file1"},
  "SampleRate": {"N": "100"},
  "Locations": {
    "L": [
      {"S": "Aberdeen MD"},
      {"S": "Warren MI"},
      {"S": "Orlando FL"}
    ]
  }
}
```

And apply the command as follows:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name Sensors \
    --item file://item.json \
    --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

Comment: Thanks! For the assignment, I am supposed to use the CLI to create the table. I am running into another problem. I'm getting this error: Error parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 31 (char 30). I initially thought it was saying each attribute needs parentheses but it did not work when I added them.

Comment: Hi @ZackLutz. You are welcome! No, I am afraid that the new problem have to do with the definition of your list `Locations`. Please, see my modified answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm...I changed my Locations definition and I'm still getting the same error. Error parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 31 (char 30)
JSON received: {"Sensor": {"S": "Sensor 1"}, \
"SensorDescription": {"S": "A"}, \
"ImageFile": {"S": "file1"}, \
"SampleRate": {"N": "100"}, \
"Locations": {"L": [{"S": "Aberdeen MD"}, {"S": "Warren MI"}, {"S": "Orlando FL"}]}}

Comment: Are you using the `item.json` file, or the inline information? Please, remove the \ characters within your JSON in the command shell, see my answer. As I told you, at least for me, the shell continuation characters within JSON are a nightmare... Please, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847981/curl-with-multiline-of-json

Comment: I was using the inline b/c the assignment called for it, but I am switching to item.json. That seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @ZackLutz.  That is great! I am happy to know that you were able to make the AWS operation work. Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you need further help.