# How to execute curl command stored in heredoc in bash script?

Tags: bash, curl, heredoc

When write bash scripts, I want to store my whole curl command in `heredoc` to get a better layout. The following works fine:

```sh
#/bin/bash

read -r -d '' command1 <<- MULTI_STRING_SCOPE
  curl -v www.stackoverflow.com
MULTI_STRING_SCOPE
```

But when add some json data with the `-d` option, the command is executed weirdly. For example:

```sh
#/bin/bash

read -r -d '' command2 <<- MULTI_STRING_SCOPE
  curl -v www.stackoverflow.com
    -d '{
      "hello":"world"
    }'
MULTI_STRING_SCOPE
response2=$(${command2})
```

Wrong logs from terminal:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}'
```

And it seems that the curl take line `}'` as a seperated url, and thus the json data not sent as a unit.

How to solve the problem? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Storing commands as strings is a bad idea; it may make the layout better, but the parsing is a confusing mess. Basically, variables are for storing data, not executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) In cases like this, I'd strongly recommend using functions instead of variables. (Note: some people recommend `eval` for things like this, but that just opens up new sorts of parsing confusion. That way lies madness and really weird bugs.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson That's really something. I once learned things about the story of `data and command`, but I just did not recognize myself got engaged in this situation. Thx for your tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847981/curl-with-multiline-of-json) to make `heredoc` work with curl command.

As the comment made by @Gordon Davisson in current post, we should not mix command with data. Since the json data set to `-d` option is only data and other parts is command, so I decide to use `heredoc` to store only the json data and remain other parts to be command itself, rather than store them in string by `heredoc`.

The result bash script should be something like this:

```sh
#/bin/bash

response3=$(curl -v www.stackoverflow.com \
  -d @- <<- MULTI_STRING_SCOPE
        {
            "hello":"world"
        }
    MULTI_STRING_SCOPE
  )
```

Notice: `heredoc` indent only works with tab, not with blanks. Be careful, especially when you are working with editors like `Visual Studio Code`, which may have already set indent as blanks for you.

Comment: What actual value does the here document provide here, though? Wouldn't it be simpler and clearer to just pass in a multi-line string?

Comment: @tripleee To the case I gave above, the here document is not necessary. In my fact situation, I need to send data in json format with '-d' option, with variable substitution to that json data at the same time. Because there are so many double quotes in json, I choose `-d '{"json":"data"}'` to work with single quote, and in single quote the variable substitution seems not work, so I turn my way to `here document`. Is this make sense, or it can also be achieved by multi-line string in a simple way?

Comment: You can't get variable substitution inside single quotes. A here document is actually not a bad solution for this scenario; other solutions include "seesaw quoting", like `'{"key" :"'"$value"'"}'` (which is just as messy as escaping all literal double quotes with a backslash) or using an external utility like `sed` to replace placeholder tokens in an otherwise static string or document.

Comment: I learned a lot, thank you @tripleee